# SQL Server cross-table join

Tags: sql, sql-server

For each AVI there can have multiple AAIs. What I want to do is find the first non-null UserID for each AVI sorted by AAI in ascending order. I then want to get the username of that user id from the user table.

So in the example below, AVI 165 would return William. i.e. it would have sorted by AAI, ignored the userid associated with 415 as this is null, returned userid 58 (corresponding to AAI416) and joined this to the user table to get William.

Table: IDS

```
AAI   AVI   UserId
------------------
415   165   NULL
416   165   58 
417   165   67     
210   510   71     
211   510   NULL    
433   534   262
```

Table: Username

```
UserId  UserName
----------------
 1      John
58      William
33      Lucy
45      Haley
51      Rob
```

I've tried it with various complex lookups, and thought I had it with this fairly simple query but it doesn't cater for the null values i.e. returns null where the first AAI has a null user value.

```
select
    u.username
from
    (select 
         avi, min(aai) as aaid 
     from 
         IDS
     group by
         avi) as au
inner join
    IDS as aa on aa.aai = au.aaid
inner join
    "user" as u on u.userid = aa.userid
```

I also tried various sub-queries along these lines but they returned all results for each AAI, not just the first.

```
select ui.username, aa.avi
from "user" as ui
join dbo.IDS as aa
on aa.userid=
(select top 1 userid 
from dbo.IDS as aa
where aa.userid = ui.userid
)
```

Any pointer/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample output? You've provided sample data, but it's not clear to me what you want returned from your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a way to get the first.  `row_number()` does this:

```
select t.*, un.*
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by avi order by aai) as seqnum
      from ids i
      where userid is not null
     ) i join
     username un
     on i.userid = un.userid
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: That's great, does exactly what I need standalone. However this is part of a bigger query which I didn't mention in the post as I didn't want to overcomplicate, and when I put it into the bigger query I hit an issue with error ' Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS'. The larger query is is selecting other data from the ids and other tables, and so I have this subquery as one of the select values in the main query. e.g. select ids.name, ids. description, username= (this subquery) from ids. How do I embed as I need to? Thanks

Comment: @TL1 . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  You should ask a new question, if this isn't really the question you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
CREATE TABLE #IDS (AAI INT, AVI INT, UserID INT)
INSERT INTO #IDS VALUES (415,165,NULL),(416,165,58),(417,165,67),(210,510,71)

CREATE TABLE #Username (UserId INT, UserName VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #Username VALUES (1,'JOHN'),(58,'William'), (71,'Lucy')


SELECT #Username.username,
       ca.AAI,
       ca.AVI,
       ca.UserID
FROM #Username
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
           AAI,
           AVI,
           UserID
    FROM #IDS
    WHERE #IDS.UserID = #Username.UserID
    ORDER BY #IDS.AAI ASC
) AS ca;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to get the first non null userid per avi sorted by aai, and then join those userids to the username table. Something along these lines..

```
select i.avi, un.username
from username un
inner join 
(select distinct avi, min(userid) over (partition by avi order by aai) userid from ids) i 
on i.userid=un.userid and un.username is not null;
```

If duplicated data is not a concern, you could also do

```
select i.avi, un.username
from username un
inner join ids i on i.userid=un.userid and un.username is not null
where i.userid in (select min(userid) over (partition by avi order by aai) from ids)
```

Comment: This worked too thanks but I can only accept one answer. I had the same issue with this as with the accepted answer but I guess I need to ask a different question

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a groupwise minimum. See this post from MySQL for an explanation of groupwise maximum:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Please ensure your answers are stand alone and fully answer the question. Tips and ideas to try belong in the comments. Links are helpful as a reference but the required information to answer the question needs to be present in the answer so that if the links break the answer is still useful.